# create drop down menu on click of an image

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I want to create a button for my android application that on click action opens a drop down menu list.

Something similar the menu button of Go Launcher as this:

[image]   [image]

I don't want to use Action bar; I read about the [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) and [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) but they are introduced only from API Level 11, and I want to support from API 4.

There is some simple method or library to implement these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this library that does something similar:

[NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)

It is simple to use and efficient!!

Answer (score 0):

I found another library which is perfectly suitable for this task.

[DroppyMenu](https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy)

Very Simple to use and have support of adding custom view in menu